# How can I check if Currency.getAvailableCurrencies() contain my String value?

Tags: java, currency

I need to check if `Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()` contains
my currency which is a string

I've tried this

```
if(Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().contains("my currency")){
  // do something
}
```

but that returns `false`, but it contains `"my currency"`?

Comment: What does `Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()` return?

Comment: all currencies included in Currency Set

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Here's the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getAvailableCurrencies--. As you can see, it returns a Set<Currency>. A Set<Currency> will never, ever, ever contain a String. It can contain a Currency. It can have a Currency whose currencyCode or displayName (which are Strings) is equal to another String. But it can't contain a String.

Comment: [SSP, CHF, VUV, LKR, AWG, UZS, MNT, DOP, MXN, TPE, KHR, PYG, GWP, UAH, AZN, FRF, WST, IQD, USD, BSD, GIP, AZM, MDL, FKP, CDF, TWD, KPW, VEF, EGP, XXX, LRD, NGN, ANG, LVL, RWF, BZD, CNY, AFN, XDR, OMR, YER, ALL, NAD, SGD, KWD, IEP, RSD, KMF, MAD, ZAR, ITL, XBB, PLN, ADP, NLG, BAM, ,  .....]
that's all return currencies, and my value in it, but my if don't find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Currency.getAvailableCurrencies()` returns `Set<Currency>` [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getAvailableCurrencies--), so you are trying to check `String` in `Set` of `Currency` objects which returns `false` always. You need to create `Currency` object with the input string, Use [Currency.getInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Currency.html#getInstance-java.lang.String-) to get the `Currency` instance

```
if(Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().contains(Currency.getInstance("my currency")))
```

Comment: oh, thanks a lot, now everything finds

Comment: @Deadpool isnt that pointless because `Currency.getInstance` only returns available Currencies and therefore will either fail (with an Exception) or, if it returns an Currency, the Currency will always be in the Set of available currencies

Comment: i don't think so he is going to enter wrong `Currency` when he is working with that, i want to give that chance to OP let him deal with exception if we get that stage @codeflush.dev

Comment: @Deadpool yeah, I mean isn't it just pointless to even check if the Currency instance is in that Set? Because you'll never get your hands on a Currency instance that is NOT in that Set. Calling `Currency.getInstance` should be enough, if that succeeds without an Exception the Currency is available

Answer (score 3):

As @JBNizet said in the comments, the method returns a `Set` of `Currency`.

You can check if your currency is available using this snippet:

```java
Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().stream()
              .map(Currency::getCurrencyCode)
              .anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual("my currency"));
```

Everything that may be returned by `Currency.getInstance` is always in that Set, so testing via `Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().contains(Currency.getInstance("my currency"))` is basically pointless.

When running this snippet:

```java
    @Test
    public void currency() {
        final Set<Currency> currencies = Currency.getAvailableCurrencies();
        System.out.println(currencies.size());

        for (char c0 = '0'; c0 <= 'Z'; c0 = inc(c0)) {
            for (char c1 = '0'; c1 <= 'Z'; c1 = inc(c1)) {
                for (char c2 = '0'; c2 <= 'Z'; c2 = inc(c2)) {
                    final String currencyCode = new String(new char[]{c0, c1, c2});
                    try {
                        final Currency currency = Currency.getInstance(currencyCode);

                        if (!currencies.contains(currency)) {
                            System.out.println("found currency that is not available: " + currency);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) { }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Currency.getAvailableCurrencies().size());
    }

    private char inc(char c) {
        if (c == '9') {
            return 'A';
        } else {
            return ++c;
        }
    }
```

You'll never find one that is not available